# not able to compile java program shows some files are missing

Tags: system-installation, java, compiling

While compiling a program the command bar shows as in the above image how can i overcome

[image]

this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should install Java Development Kit to your system:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

and then retry.